# Use scanf with defined value

Tags: arrays, c, string, scanf

I have an array of characters in the size of SIZE

```
#define SIZE 50
int main(){
    char str[SIZE];
    return 0;
}
```

I want to read a sentence into it up to SIZE characters, using scanf.

I know I can do something such as

```
scanf("%50s", str);
```

but I can't find a way to do it with the defined value of SIZE (something like

```
scanf("%SIZEs", str);
```

I don't want to read character by character until '\0' or '\n' or SIZE -1 (for '\0') characters found.

How can I do so?
Thanks!

Comment: While it isn't the question, you might be better served by writing your own `int get_word(char *buf, size_t bufsize)`  function, which uses `getc` ans `ungetc`.

Comment: Note, your *field width* specifier should be, at most, the size of the buffer minus one. That is, `char buf[256]; scanf("%255s", buf);`.

Answer (score 1):

If the length is a define like in your code, you might want to do something like this:

```
#define _STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) _STRINGIFY(x)
[...]
scanf("%" STRINGIFY(SIZE) "s", str);
```

The `#x` in the macro definition actually surrounds the parameter of the macro with quotes, so this would result in:

```
scanf("%" "50" "s", str);
```

in your case. The extra indirection is necessary for the preprocessor to substitute WIDTH with "50" and not with "WIDTH".

Comment: This means `str` must be of `SIZE + 1`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Thats been a bug in the original code I carried over.

Comment: Beware. `_STRINGIFY` is a [reserved identifier](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3): "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

Comment: Please don't leave answer in state where it has buffer overflow bug, and that it is only mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to read a sentence into it up to SIZE characters, using scanf.

Using `"%s"` will fail to read a *sentence* like "Hello World!" as `"%s"` does not save *white-spaces*.

---

> I don't want to read character by character until '\0' or '\n' or SIZE -1 (for '\0') characters found.

1. Instead of *character by character*, use `fgets()`: `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);` (Additional code needed to consume extra characters.)
2. If still wanting to use `scanf()` to read to end of line, see following.
   Be sure the format *width* parameter is 1 less than the buffer size. [@Oka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72491836/use-scanf-with-defined-value/72492409#comment128058747_72491836)

Example:

```
#define STRINGIFY_HELPER(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_HELPER(x)
#define SENTENCE_MAX 50
#define SENTENCE_SIZE (SENTENCE_MAX + 1)

char str[SENTENCE_SIZE];
str[0] = '\0'; // In case input begins with a '\n'
//    v--------------------------------v Read and save non-'\n' characters.
scanf("%" STRINGIFY(SENTENCE_MAX) "[^\n]%*[^\n]", str);
//                                      ^-----^ Also eat extra non-'\n' characters. 
// Consume 1 '\n'
scanf("%*1[\n]");
```

More robust code would also check the return values of `scanf()`.