# When I input multiple words with scanf("%s%s%s", word0, word1, word2), the first character of every word except the last word is missing

Tags: c, scanf

Here's my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char word0[4], word1[4], word2[4];
    scanf("%s%s%s", word0, word1, word2);
    printf("word0: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf("%c", word0[i]);
    printf("\nword1: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf("%c", word1[i]);
    printf("\nword2: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf("%c", word2[i]);
}
```

Input:

```
zxcv abcd 1234
```

And it outputs:

```
word0: xcv
word1: bcd
word2: 1234
```

I changed the code from

```c
scanf("%s%s%s", word0, word1, word2);
```

to

```c
scanf("%s", word0);
scanf("%s", word1);
scanf("%s", word2);
```

and then I debug the code:
(For this case I was input with `zxcv qwer 0235`)
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH4bO.png) [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRkhk.png)
I am totally unexpected with those result.
How can `scanf()` modify the variable after the line has executed?

Comment: ***Don't Skimp On Buffer Size!!!***, you will avoid the *too-short-by-one-byte* causing stack-smashing errors and Undefined Behavior in your code. `char word0[64], word1[64], word2[64];` and try again.... Don't loop printing characters.... Simply `puts (word0);` and `puts (word1);` , etc... for output.

Comment: Remember, you must provide space for the `'\0'` (nul-terminating character) at the end of each string. That takes a minimum of **5-bytes** for a **4-character** string... Now with your string properly terminated, if you want to loop over each char, just do `for (int i = 0; word0[i]; i++) { putchar (word0[i]); }; putchar ('\n');` (the newline is just to tidy up)

Comment: You can avoid this problem to by using `scanf()` correctly. You must use the *field-width* modifier to protect your array bounds when using `"%s"`. That means using `"%3s"` (with your original 4-byte arrays) or `"%63s"` (with my suggested 64-byte arrays). Always `size - 1` to ensure 1-byte is reserved for the nul-character...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Does %s implicitly append '\0' to the end of the string inputted?

Comment: Yes!! AS LONG AS YOU LEAVE SPACE FOR IT -- otherwise, `scanf()` will happily continue writing OUTSIDE your array boundary corrupting the other variables on your program stack (which you found out `:)`

Comment: Always check the return value of scanf.

Comment: Useful to add a _width_ to `"%s"` [based on a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72492409/2410359).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the classic -- *too-short-by-one* byte issue with your arrays. Continuing from my comments. In C, a string is defined as a sequence of characters terminated by the `'\0'` (*nul-character*). This is how all functions that take a string as a parameter know where the string ends.

To prevent your problem, you must always specify the *field-width* modifier when using the `"%s"` or `"%[..]"` conversion specifiers to fill an array. You must manually provide the *field-width* modifier as it cannot be specified with a named constant or provided as a parameter to `scanf()`. The field-width modifier is set to `size-of-array - 1` to limit the number of characters `scanf()` will read to one less than the size of the array -- ensuring 1-byte remains for the nul-terminating character.

For your arrays that would be `"%3s"` -- which shows the *off-by-one* error you have. What happens is you write beyond the end of your array overwriting the address for the first character of the next array, and so on.

To use `scanf()` correctly, you must ALWAYS check the return, and if filling an array ALWAYS use the *field-width* modifier.

Putting a short example together from your code, and showing a couple of ways to output, you can do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 64   /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */

int main() {
    /* use a constant to set array size (not Magic-Numbers) */
    char word0[MAXC], word1[MAXC], word2[MAXC];
    
    /* prompt for input */
    puts ("enter 3 space separated words");
    
    /* ALWAYS use the field-width modifier filling arrays and
     * ALWAYS check the scanf return.
     */
    if (scanf("%63s%63s%63s", word0, word1, word2) != 3) {
        fputs ("error: reading words.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    putchar ('\n');                     /* tidy up with newline */
    
    fputs ("word0: ", stdout);
    for (int i = 0; word0[i]; i++) {    /* if you want to loop chars */
        putchar (word0[i]);
    }
    putchar ('\n');                     /* tidy up with newline */
    
    fputs ("word1: ", stdout);
    puts (word1);                       /* otherwise just output the word */
    
    fputs ("word2: ", stdout);
    puts (word2);
}
```

(**Note:** `puts()` will always append a `'\n'` to the string being output. If you need end-of-line control, then use `fputs()` which doesn't. The point being, you don't need to call the variadic `printf()` function when there are no conversion in your output string.)

**Example Use/Output**

Using your example:

```
$./bin/3words
enter 3 space separated words
xzcv abcd 1234

word0: xzcv
word1: abcd
word2: 1234
```

Or three different sized words:

```
$ ./bin/3words
enter 3 space separated words
My Elephant Sings

word0: My
word1: Elephant
word2: Sings
```

Let me know if you have further questions -- and consider reading all input with `fgets()` to read a line at a time and avoid the `scanf()` pitfalls...

Comment: Wow sir, this is good one, thank you for sharing 

Comment: Oh, well thank you for stopping by the day after Thanksgiving! In food coma from too much food, and partially insane from having too many children back home. All good times.

Answer (score 0):

in the c++ their is a null terminator for an array. so you can't use an array of 4 character to store an array of 4 elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char word0[5], word1[5], word2[5];
    scanf("%s%s%s", word0, word1, word2);
    printf("word0: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf("%c", word0[i]);
    printf("\nword1: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf("%c", word1[i]);
    printf("\nword2: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf("%c", word2[i]);
}
```